# Chrome Dev Tools is hiding errors and can't figure out where to turn them back on

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This started earlier this week. I guess I might have clicked on something to cause this, no idea. I haven't been able to figure out how to change it back to normal.

Basically it is hiding errors as you can see in the picture. There are 2 errors, but all it shows is a red box. Clicking on it doesn't do anything. Selecting All Levels instead of Default Levels doesn't do anything.

Seems to happen intermittently too. It doesn't do this all the time, just sometimes.

What gives?

[image: Hidden errors]

4/9 - Apparently other devs are having the same issue:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/u4YdVeVlTP8/kVPVwgtLBwAJ

Comment: I added another way to show hidden errors which I bet is what you are experiencing.

Comment: Unfortunately, still having the issue. "Hide Network" was already unchecked and I'm not using an ad-blocker... probably one of few that isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is fixed now in: `Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 0):

Under default levels, you can enable "verbose".

Also, you can show hidden network errors by clicking the gear on the right of the developer tools and unchecking the "hide network" box.

When certain ad-blockers block network requests, they often show as network errors in the Chrome dev tools console.

Comment: Tried that. Changed to All Levels which includes verbose and still the same issue.